# Dictionary inside DataTemplate dosen't update the UI even after implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a dictionary which I am populating by iterating through an other dictionary. At some point on button click command, I am updating the value of one of the keys. Problem is it never updates the UI with the updated value. But when I keep a break point, I see the value of the dictionary updates. Please help.

```
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        storage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class VM
{
    public ICommand HomingSectionAcceptButtonCommand { get; set; }

    private Dictionary<EnumLocalizer<HomingLocationEnums>,string> _homingItems;
    public Dictionary<EnumLocalizer<HomingLocationEnums>, string> HomingItems
    {
        get => _homingItems;
        set
        {
            Set(ref _homingItems, value);
        }
    }

    public VM()
    {
        foreach (var item in _readOrWriteHomingDataHelper.HomingConfiguration)
        {
            HomingItems.Add(new EnumLocalizer<HomingLocationEnums>() { Value = (HomingLocationEnums)Enum.Parse(typeof(HomingLocationEnums), item.Key) }, item.Value);
        }

        HomingSectionAcceptButtonCommand = new RelayCommand<EnumLocalizer<HomingLocationEnums> >(UpdateOffsetsFromDataBase);
    }

    private async void UpdateOffsetsFromDataBase(EnumLocalizer<HomingLocationEnums> homingLocation)
    {
        if (HomingItems.ContainsKey(homingLocation))
        {
            //UI doesn't update the value with ABC
            HomingItems[homingLocation] = "ABC";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my enum (which is not important)

```
public enum HomingLocationEnums
{
    BarCodeScanning = 0,
    Aspiration,
    Framing,
    LABHomeOrFrame,
    LeftScan,
    RightScan,
    LeftAspiration,
    RightAspiration,
    LeftFraming,
    RightFraming
}
```

Xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HomingTemplate">

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                x:Name="lstHomingItemsTemplate"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding HomingItems}" Margin="0,20" 
                SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeMedium}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Value}" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeMedium}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,0,0,0" 
                            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.HomingSectionAcceptButtonCommand,ElementName=lstHomingItemsTemplate}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Key}">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Accept" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dictionary` doesn't implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) (in contrast to `ObservableCollection`). Therefore adding/removing/moving items of the collection won't update the binding. If you want to stay with the `Dictionary` as a binding source you have to raise `PropertyChanged`:

```
foreach (var item in _readOrWriteHomingDataHelper.HomingConfiguration)
{
  HomingItems.Add(new EnumLocalizer<HomingLocationEnums>() { Value = (HomingLocationEnums)Enum.Parse(typeof(HomingLocationEnums), item.Key) }, item.Value);
}

RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.HomingItems));
```

Alternatively use `ObservableCollection` as a binding source for the `ListView`. You can create a data model type that consolidates key and value as class attrinutes (properties) for later binding. Raising `PropertyChanged` each time the `Dictionary` was modified can result in bad performance and other side effects, especially with big collections.

Comment: Sure thank you. I will use an observable collection instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although I accepted the answer, this is what finally worked for me [`ObservableDictionary`](https://www.broculos.net/2014/03/wpf-editable-datagrid-and.html). In case if it helps someone here is the entire code. Call this code by creating an instance of `ObservablePairCollection` class from outside. Syntactically same as a `Dictionary`.

```
public class ObservablePairCollection<TKey, TValue> : ObservableCollection<Pair<TKey, TValue> >
{
    public ObservablePairCollection()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public ObservablePairCollection(IEnumerable<Pair<TKey, TValue> > enumerable)
        : base(enumerable)
    {
    }

    public ObservablePairCollection(List<Pair<TKey, TValue> > list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    public ObservablePairCollection(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        foreach (var kv in dictionary)
        {
            Add(new Pair<TKey, TValue>(kv));
        }
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Add(new Pair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }
}

public class Pair<TKey, TValue> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected TKey _key;
    protected TValue _value;

    public TKey Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set
        {
            if (
                (_key == null && value != null)
                || (_key != null && value == null)
                || !_key.Equals(value))
            {
                _key = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Key");
            }
        }
    }

    public TValue Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (
                (_value == null && value != null)
                || (_value != null && value == null)
                || (_value != null && !_value.Equals(value)))
            {
                _value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }

    public Pair()
    {
    }

    public Pair(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public Pair(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kv)
    {
        Key = kv.Key;
        Value = kv.Value;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```